# how to use ORM technologies in fully grown existing multi threaded java database app?

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, orm

How to use ORM technologies in fully grown existing multi threaded java database app? 
Application is developed nearly 7 years back. It has got Business object and DAO.
is it feasible? Now our application faces connection bottleneck and data integrity issue because of multi threaded database access. This occurs at highly concurrent situations.

how to synchronize insert or update in same table my multiple thread.?
I know it can done by setting isolation level which may affect performance (TRANSACTION_SERIALIZABLE). But thought of re structuring the application for scalability. May be using ORM.

Comment: Please define "fully grown". You can use Object Relational Mapping to do? Maybe...

Comment: Fully grown means huge application which is developed nearly 7 years back. We are maintaining and enhancing the app for years. It does not use any ORM technology like spring or hibernate. What we have is POJO's and DAO classes.

Answer (score 1):

If you are managing (getting/releasing) database connections correctly using JDBC (I believe you use this), then using a ORM will not help you at all, because ORM will not do any magic about resource management. It just gets and releases resources at proper points (if it is configured properly).

By the way if you have developed your project using JDBC and SQL, it will be lots of work to change it to an ORM such as `Hibernate` or `JPA`.

If you are not sure that your resource management is correct, use `Spring JDBC (JdbcTemplate)`. It ensures that resources are always released properly, and well it is JDBC, and it can be less work to do for your project.

Comment: Thank you. But it is not about connection release. We are using connection pooling nearly about 70 connections in the pool. But when we have more than 200 to 700 users we start facing DB lock and data integrity issue. Application is multi threaded.

Comment: Well it is strange, we are managing more than 1500 online users with a connection pool of 25 connections (and we have complex queries). I believe you don't release the connection as soon as you are done with it, or maybe it's your DB that's the bottleneck. What is your database?

Comment: Postgresql. Ok. You are correct. some part of application is not designed as thread pool which was causing the connection pool to exhaust and causing db connection bottleneck. Could you tell me how do you handle when multiple threads update or insert the same table.?

Comment: I have not worked with Postgresql; but my experience in Oracle is: if you want to update same record in multiple threads, threads shall wait for previous ones, otherwise indexes can help. By creating proper indexes in Oracle, only record locks happen (not the entire table lock).

Answer (score 0):

You can use ORM for multi-threaded java applications. But if you already have  data integrity issues then ORM will not help a lot, except you also add locking. (JPA provides support of optimistic and pesimistic locking.)